# Left join either returns all records or none

Tags: sql-server-2012, left-join, sql

I have two tables DEPARTMENT and BUDGET. I want to return all Departments even if they are not present in BUDGET table. I am using following query but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
SELECT dept_name FROM department
LEFT JOIN budget ON budget.dept_id = department.dept_id
AND budget.division = 5 AND budget.year = 2015
```

The above query returns departments from all divisions and not just division 5. If I use WHERE clause then it doesn't return any record even though I am using LEFT JOIN. What am I doing wrong?

**SQL FIDDLE ADDED**
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d4b07/12

**EDIT AGAIN**

Looks like I found the query I wanted. This is returning one result 'Legal' in SQL fiddle I posted above and this is what I wanted.

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.name, B.budget_year FROM department D  
LEFT JOIN budget B ON D.ID = B.department_id   
AND D.division_id = B.division_id  
AND B.budget_year = 2015  
WHERE D.division_id = 11
```

Comment: Put the conditions on `budget` in the `on` clause instead of the `where` clause.

Comment: I am already using `budget` in the `on` clause instead of `where` but it is not working.

Comment: You should edit the question with sample data and desired results.  Your question is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query worked.

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.name, B.budget_year FROM department D
LEFT JOIN budget B ON D.ID = B.department_id 
AND D.division_id = B.division_id
AND B.budget_year = 2015
WHERE D.division_id = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your division id is not in the department table. If you have a division id in that table use that in your where clause.

You want all departments even if they are not in the budget so regardless of the existence of the budget table you get the department

Try:

```
SELECT dept_name FROM department
LEFT JOIN budget ON budget.dept_id = department.dept_id and budget.division = department.division AND budget.year = 2015
WHERE department.division = 5
```

Comment: Oh I do have Division Id in department table. Totally forgot about that. Now if I use this too in condition such as AND department.division = budget.division then it doesn't bring any records.

Comment: Updated answer with query. Is this how your query looks?

Comment: I used this query and it is bringing all records even though division 5 only contain 1 record.

Comment: Changed query. It is hard to write it properly not seeing the data...sorry. If this does not work then you should double check that there is a division 5 department.